# Openshift oc login failed from mac

Tags: openshift

Whenever I try to login to Openshift through CLI I get the following error.

error: dial tcp: lookup api.rhocp1.xxx.com on xxx.xxx.225.1:53: no such host - verify you have provided the correct host and port and that the server is currently running.

But from windows it works absolutely fine. Strange.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've seen this before with proxy or VPN usage. Do you happen to have a VPN, proxy connection, or firewall between your Mac and the API server that perhaps your Windows machine doesn't have?

Comment: Yes Will, we are using the VPN to connect to the API server. But the set up is same on Windows machine as well.  But it works on Windows.  Tried with more than one Mac laptops. Same issue.

Comment: forgot to mention.  On the same Mac, I can access the web console. But just the CLI is failing to connect.

Comment: were you able to solve the problem? I'm also on mac and was able to do oc login before but i suddenly got the same error as above.